# MySql sorting float data type

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, floating-point

Hi guys im having a problem sorting a column named "change" which is a reserved word that has a data type of "FLOAT" in the database.

tried different ways but still cant get it.

```
"select * from data order by CAST('change' AS SIGNED) DESC";
"select * from data order by ABS(change) DESC";
"select * from data order by ABS(change - float) DESC";
"select CAST(change as float) AS ABC* from data order by ABC DESC";
```

i tried lots of different combinations but still no luck[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2bp7.png)

heres a picture of my sample database
thank you in advance!

Comment: MySQL uses back-ticks for delimited identifiers.

Comment: *"but still no luck"* -- no luck on what? On sorting? Or do you get a syntax error?

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql

Comment: Most dbms have the ANSI/ISO SQL standard's double quotes, i.e. `"CHANGE"`.

Comment: using your first query without the double quotes (select * from data order by CAST('change' AS SIGNED) DESC;), ran successfully on my workbench 6.3 using mysql server 5.7

Comment: no luck of sorting.. my first try was the single quote then the cast and putting the cast after select.. the answer for this question was the back ticks by sagi.. no need for cast ..Thank you for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Use back ticks

```
ORDER BY `CHANGE` DESC
```

Each RDBMS has different way of handling reserved words. MySQL uses back ticks : `

The error you got has nothing to do with casting .

Comment: The back ticks works! thank you for that. took nearly 3 hours of single quotes, casting rearranging the statement and all i have to do is the back ticks. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As user 'sagi' suggested, using the reserved word "change", theres no need for casting or single quotes but instead back ticks work on the original question. for mac its on the left side of number 1 on the keyword. Thank you all!